# Passing options to templates in knockout 1.3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, templating, knockout-templating

In knockoutjs 1.2.1 I could do:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'Bar', foreach: persons, templateOptions:{fooMode: true} }"/>

<script id='Bar'>
    {{if $item.fooMode}} FOO! {{/if}}
</script>
```

Which I have tried to translate to knockout 1.3.0beta as

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'Bar', foreach: persons, templateOptions:{fooMode: true} }"/>

<script id='Bar'>
    <span data-bind="if: $item.fooMode">FOO!</span>
</script>
```

But the new native template engine doesn't respect templateOptions.

Is there some other way I can pass arbitrary data into a template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you discovered, the native template engine does not support `templateOptions` which was a wrapper to the jQuery Template plug-in's `options` functionality.

Two ways that you could go:
Place your data on your view model and use `$root.fooMode` or `$parent.fooMode` inside of your template.  This would be the easiest option.

Otherwise, if you don't want the value in your view model, then you can use a custom binding to manipulate the context like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templateWithOptions = {
    init: ko.bindingHandlers.template.init,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        //if options were passed attach them to $data
        if (options.templateOptions) {
           context.$data.$item = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.templateOptions);
        } 
        //call actual template binding
        ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        //clean up
        delete context.$data.$item;
    } 
}
```

Here is a sample in use: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tFJuH/

Note that in a `foreach` scenario, you would find your options on `$parent.$item` rather than just `$item`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had a feeling that bindingHandlers might get me where I wanted, but it would have taken me a long time to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. Although it didn't initially work, I  got it going by changing context.$data.$item to context.$templateOptions instead.

Comment: Note that options ($item) are not passed after you apply the bindings for the first time - as they are deleted - which makes Adding and Modifying elements unusable

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest Sanderson's proposal where you would pass new literal to template data that contains model and extra data (template options).

```
data-bind="template: { name: 'myTemplate', data: { model: $data, someOption: someValue } }"
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/b9WWF/

Source https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/246#issuecomment-3775317

Comment: Vukoje, Very awesome insight -- saved me! Very good, non-clugy, adaptive approach -- Thx!